# Return non-returning function from Promise results in Warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I have a nodejs express app and I use a library which has a typical callback interface for executing functions. My persistence layer uses a promise based approach. I have the following code which bothers me

```
getUserByName('dave')
  .then(function (user) {
    // check stuff and call the callback with success
    return cb(null, true);
  })
  .catch((err) => cb(err, false));
```

Problem: the `cb(null, true)` functions returns `undefined` and the promise ends with this warning `a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it`.

I can fix this by running the callback and then do `return null` like this:

```
    // check stuff and call the callback with success
    cb(null, true);
    return null;
```

But now I'm asking myself is it really waiting for the callback to finish? Is this the correct way to handle this kind of warning? I have the feeling I'm doing it wrong.

I remember having the same problem when writing an express middleware and then inside a promise calling the `next()` function to jump to the next middleware. It also returns `undefined`. Any suggestions to handle this?

Comment: try returning `null` from the callback `cb(null, true)`. This warning shows for creating a runaway promise. [more info](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it)

Comment: Thanks for the response but I can not control what the cb  returns because it is a external library. For example the `next()` method in express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the proper solution would of course be to switch to a framework that doesn't use node-style callbacks and leverages promises, so that you could simply `return` your promise and wouldn't need to call any callbacks passed to you.

If that is not possible, you still should not call such callbacks from your normal code. The warning is correct, you are calling something (the callback) that does more asynchronous work (creates other promises) but are not returning that into your chain ("forgetting" to wait for it), a common mistake. Your explicit `return null` suppresses this warning correctly, but there's actually a much better way:
Write your code as if you already were returning promises, and then invoke [`.asCallback`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html) which is dedicated for this very purpose (including not issuing warnings):

```
getUserByName('dave')
  .then(function (user) {
    // check stuff and call the callback with success
    return true;
  })
  .asCallback(cb)
```

Answer (score 1):

> But now I'm asking myself is it really waiting for the callback to
>   finish? Is this the correct way to handle this kind of warning? I have
>   the feeling I'm doing it wrong.

The Javascript execution in node.js is single threaded so the code is waiting for any synchronous code in `cb()` to finish.  If `cb()` does async operations (which the warning you are getting makes me think it is), then your code is NOT waiting for those asynchronous operations to finish.

Whether or not your work-around is the correct way to handle that warning depends upon what is happening in the callback and whether your code needs to wait for any async operations in that callback to actually complete.  If your code does not need to wait for them, then adding the empty `return` is perfectly fine and just tells the promise library that you are purposely not returning a promise that was created inside the `.then()` handler which is an OK thing to do in some circumstances.

If, on the other hand, you do need to wait for the asynchronous operations inside of the callback to complete, then you need the callback's help in order to be able to do that by making it either return a promise or for it to have a completion callback itself (though the promise would be a lot easier in this case).